# Do Begin & End in SQL Server work as Transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactions

In SQL Scripting in SQL Server

If I have a block of Begin ... End

```
BEGIN

UPDATE Table1
SET Column1 = 1

UPDATE Table2
SET Column2 = 2

UPDATE Table3
SET Column3 = 3

END
```

in this case does it mean that all 3 update statement should pass together ?

I mean if First  & Second update were successful but the 3rd failed, does that mean all 3 updates will rollback? or Table1 & Table2 are updated only and no update to Table3

In another words

Is the script above equivalent to

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column1 = 1

UPDATE Table2
SET Column2 = 2

UPDATE Table3
SET Column3 = 3
```

or it is equivalent to

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

UPDATE Table1
SET Column1 = 1

UPDATE Table2
SET Column2 = 2

UPDATE Table3
SET Column3 =  3

COMMIT;
```

Comment: To summarise :) **no** begin/end is not equivalent at all.

Comment: @DaleBurrell you mean it is not a transaction, so if the first update success and the 3rd failed it still update the 1st without rolling back

Comment: Adding `begin/end` has no effect at all on the "Atomicity" of the T-SQL within. As the answer states begin/end are for the control of flow e.g. allowing an if statement to contain multiple expressions to carry out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BEGIN and END define a statement block, it is for control of flow. BEGIN TRANSACTION / COMMIT TRANSACTION / ROLLBACK TRANSACTION are for a database transaction. If a database is in a consistent state before a transaction is started then the database will be in a consistent state after the transaction completes. If there is a failure before commit transaction then all the changes made to the database will be rolled back to the point when the transaction began.